# Execute command on host (windows) from vagrant guest (centos)

Tags: windows, centos, vagrant

I'm trying to figure if there is a way to execute a windows command from a centos vagrant box. In other words, execute host commands from vagrant guest.

I tried to find an answer but all I can find is the opposite (host to guest).

Thank you!

Comment: can you detail a bit ? if strictly you want to run at anytime time a windows command from your guest VM, its not possible, the guest has no control whatsoever on the host. If you want to run during provisioning it could be possible but it would depend the use case

Comment: The idea is execute commands in the Windows host once you entered in the vagrant guest with `vagrant ssh`. I thought that it could be possible since there are shared folders between the host and the guest. One solution would be executing commands from the Linux guest to the Windows host   (having OpenSSH installed) via ssh too, that could work?

Comment: you can check the vagrant trigger plugin and run a command after you run vagrant ssh. it can also run command on the host so should fit what you want to achieve